# funções estão a dar conflito e não estão a funcionar

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho que ordenar 4 palavras por ordem alfabética e por ordem reversa.

As minhas funções estão da dar conflito mas quando retiro uma a outra já funciona e vice versa.

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");

function ordena() {

  var alf = ['Ana', 'Aida', 'Mário' , 'Daniela'];
  alf.sort(); 

  console.log(alf);
  alert(alf);
}

const name = document.querySelector(".name");

function reverse() {

  var alf = ['Ana', 'Aida', 'Mário' , 'Daniela'];
  alf.reverse(); 

  console.log(alf);
  alert(alf);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ordena()">Ordem alfabética</button>
<button onclick="reverse()">Reversa Ordem alfabética </button>
```

Comment: O problema é que vc declarou a constante `name` duas vezes. Declare-a apenas uma vez (se bem que nesse código vc não usa ela pra nada e poderia até removê-la, mas caso esteja usando em outras partes do código, basta declarar apenas uma vez)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o JavaScript está detectando a declaração das variáveis **const name** e **var alf** duas vezes.

Você poderia simplificar o código:

1. Retirando os pontos e vírgula.
2. Declarando o array **alf** com escopo global.
3. Retirando a const name pois não está sendo utilizada nas funções.

Ex:

```
//const name = document.querySelector(".name")
var alf = ['Ana', 'Aida', 'Mário', 'Daniela']

function ordena() {
  alf.sort()

  console.log(alf)
  alert(alf)
}

function reverse() {
  alf.reverse()

  console.log(alf)
  alert(alf)
}
```

```
<button onclick="ordena()">Ordem alfabética</button>
<button onclick="reverse()">Ordem alfabética Reversa</button>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda